# How to use static library in Qt 5.2?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I downloaded qt recently.

I want to create an standalone exe,
but I don't know what can I do.

In Qt5.2, the folder "(Qt)\lib" is exists, but i can't use it in Qt Creator.

So, should I build from source,
or configure Qt Creator and use the "lib***.a"?

Any ideas?

*Environment:* MinGW-32 4.8.1(TDM) / Windows 7

Comment: "the folder "(Qt)\lib" is exists, but i can't use it in Qt Creator." -> what do you mean by that? What issue exactly are you facing? Also, what do you mean by this "should I build from source"? What would you like to build from source, Qt?

Comment: The [licensing of Qt](http://qt-project.org/products/licensing) may prohibit or discourage static linking (at least for distributed software). See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10179181/841108) and read more about [LGPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License); so you should not loose your time trying that (and link your program dynamically to Qt).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: license consideration applies for any software. This is a programming site after all, not general licensing. :-)

Comment: @LaszloPapp Sorry for bad english. I searched for manything, and setted CONFIG+=static, but it always requires QtCore.dll. I need a exe without QtCore.dll(linked with libQtCore.a).

Comment: @IshiTatsuyuki To expand on Basile's comment, note that the user (that is, whoever gets your statically linked .exe) must be able to change the LGPL part, which means the Qt libraries. For practical purposes, this means you must be ready to give your source code (license does not really matter much) to whoever gets the statically linked .exe, so they can re-build it with modified (newer version, bug-fixed, whatever) LGPL Qt. Disclaimer: IANAL

Comment: @hyde: the user could also be given a bunch of object files and the instructions to relink his modified `libQt*.a` with them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have tried `CONFIG+=static`, but that is not meant for this use case. That is used when you would like to use build **your** library to be static after the end of the build.

This is not the case here because you already have static Qt libraries available, so what you wish instead, to link those statically against your executable.

You would need to use this in your qmake project file:

```
LIBS += -L/path/to/the/static/QtCore -lQtCore
```

You could also use, albeit this would make the build-system less portable across different platforms:

```
LIBS += /path/to/the/statis/QtCore/libQtCore.a
```

Comment: I tried add it to pro file, but the file is still 48KB and don't links QtCore. Qt creator looks like know the lib directory. I just want to make Qt creator use these libraries.

Comment: @IshiTatsuyuki: you are probably doing something wrong you have not shared with us. This oughta work... Provide more context...

Comment: I added qmake arguments"CONFIG+=static". Using "Rebuild all", but it seems to not link any library(I added zlib). I added "win32:" before LIB+=. Is it wrong?

Comment: @IshiTatsuyuki: have you read the post in its entirity? It explicitly writes you should _not_ use `CONFIG+=static`.

Comment: Nothing changes...Still 48KB and requires Qt5Core/Qt5Cored.dll.